# Django, unit test not working: reverse for xxx is not found. xxx is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, url

I understand there are a few questions like this on stack overflow, but none of them seem to answer my issue. I am trying to run a unit test on my pages in the project, but I keep getting this issue: "Reverse for 'page1' not found. 'page1' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

'page1' works fine when I run it with `python manage.py runserver`, but when I run `python manage.py test` it fails.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.displaylol),
    path('page1', views.page1),
    path('empty', views.empty),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tag

# Create your views here.

def displaylol(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home page")

def page1(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ecommerce/page1.html', {'tags': tags})

def empty(request):
    return HttpResponse("empty")
```

ecommerce/page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Product 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tags</h1>

        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tag</th>
                    <th>Connections</th>
                    <th>No. of products attached to</th>
                    <th>Idk</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for tag in tags %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ tag.name }}<br>
                        <small style="color: #888">ID: {{ tag.ID }}</small>
                    </td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

tests.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.

class page1Tests(TestCase):
    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('page1') # It fails the same way when I use reverse('empty') as well
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

the error:

```
(venv) xxx@xxx-MacBook 03_high_level % python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_home_view_status_code (ecommerce.tests.page1Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/OneDrive/#Development#/PROJ_NEA_03/03_high_level/ecommerce/tests.py", line 9, in test_home_view_status_code
    url = reverse('page1')
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/OneDrive/#Development#/PROJ_NEA_03/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/OneDrive/#Development#/PROJ_NEA_03/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'page1' not found. 'page1' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the view, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.displaylol),
    path('page1/', views.page1, name='page1'),
    path('empty/', views.empty),
]
```

otherwise the `reverse('page1')` will *not* work.

Comment: Yes that worked, wow that was so simple. Thanks!